# Utilizing AppSetting from web.config in Web.sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, sitemap

In a web.sitemap I am working on, I would like to make the domain part of url's more manageable by placing the domain in an AppSetting in the web.config.  I know how to do this in my C# code behind but am not sure how I would reference the AppSetting in an xml file.

Here's my AppSettings:

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="MyDomain" value="https://subdomain.mydomain.example.com/"/>
</appSettings>
```

Here's are a couple site map nodes:

```
<siteMapNode url="https://subdomain.mydomain.example.com/division/div1/default.aspx" title="Division 1" description="" roles="*"/>
<siteMapNode url="https://subdomain.mydomain.example.com/division/div2/default.aspx" title="Division 2" description="" roles="*"/>
<siteMapNode url="https://subdomain.mydomain.example.com/division/div3/default.aspx" title="Division 3" description="" roles="*"/>
```

How do I replace `"http://subdomain.mydomain.example.com/"` in the url's with MyDomain AppSetting. I've tried:

```
url="<% ConfigurationSettings.AppSetting["MyDomain"] %>/division/div1/default.aspx"
```

I got a runtime error and I'm guessing it didn't like the `<% %>`, and:

```
url="ConfigurationSettings.AppSetting["MyDomain"]/division/div1/default.aspx"
```

I got another runtime error and I'm guessing it didn't like the "" around MyDomain.